# content of variable php hide when pass to 5.2-.5.3 to 5.4+ php version

Tags: php, apache, centos, server

i have a web site build some years ago, this site for more time is hosted on server with php 5.2, now i have decided to upgrade the server , the configuaration of new server is

-Centos
-php 5.4.16
-apache 2.4

when move the site on new server , every work fine but some output of variable not work , in this variable is present some code and some special caracther example ("?:.).

in new site the output of this variable is not printed , th code is this :

```
<?php

include_once "/opt/bitnami/apache2/htdocs/inc/settings/list.php";

echo $_form['list']['two'];
?>
```

in this page (list.php) is present this code:

http://pastebin.com/egVE9ff0

i tried to insert in this variable a text example and work fine , i tried number and work fine, i tried the DOT and work fine, so the problem is   conflict between 2+ element in  in this code.

in a server with php 5.2-5.3 work fine, in a server with 5.4.16-5.5 not work

the problem is , not show the output. the source code is full white.

Answer (score 0):

Having a look at your code:

```
<?

$_form['list']['two'] = "
ciao INFORMATIVA IN BASE ALL'ART. 13 D. LGS. 196/2003
...
```

The problem is that newer version of PHP don't (by default) support `<?` a.k.a [`short_open_tag`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.short-open-tag).

The easiest way to fix it is to change `<?` to `<?php`:

```
<?php

$_form['list']['two'] = "
ciao INFORMATIVA IN BASE ALL'ART. 13 D. LGS. 196/2003
...
```

Comment: i have already tried this, and the problem persist, my server have short_open_tag active